# JS-Interpreter - changing “this” context

Tags: javascript, interpreter

[JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter) is a somewhat well-known JavaScript Interpreter. It has security advantages in that it can completely isolate your code from `document` and allows you to detect attacks such as infinite loops and memory bombs. This allows you to run externally defined code safely.

I have an object, say `o` like this:

```
let o = {
    hidden: null,
    regex: null,
    process: [
        "this.hidden = !this.visible;",
        "this.regex = new RegExp(this.validate, 'i');"
    ],
    visible: true,
    validate: "^[a-z]+$"
};
```

I'd like to be able to run the code in `process` through JS-Interpreter:

```
for (let i = 0; i < o.process.length; i++)
    interpretWithinContext(o, o.process[i]);
```

Where `interpretWithinContext` will create an interpreter using the first argument as the context, i.e. `o` becomes `this`, and the second argument is the line of code to run. After running the above code, I would expect `o` to be:

```
{
    hidden: false,
    regex: /^[a-z]+$/i,
    process: [
        "this.hidden = !this.visible;",
        "this.regex = new RegExp(this.validate, 'i');"
    ],
    visible: true,
    validate: '^[a-z]+$'
}
```

That is, `hidden` and `regex` are now set.

Does anyone know if this is possible in JS-Interpreter?

Comment: There is no function called `interpretWithinContext` i the docs of JS-Interpretter. How is it defined?

Comment: That is a function I want to define to wrap JS-Interpreter specific functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve spent a while messing around with the JS-Interpreter now, trying to figure out [from the source](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter/blob/master/interpreter.js) how to place an object into the interpreter’s scope that can be both read and modified.

Unfortunately, the way this library is built, all the useful internal things are minified so we cannot really utilize the internal things and *just* put an object inside. Attempts to add a [proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) also failed failed since the object just wasn’t used in a “normal” way.

So my original approach to this was to just fall back to providing simple utility functions to access the outside object. This is fully supported by the library and probably the safest way of interacting with it. It does require you to change the `process` code though, in order to use those functions. But as a benefit, it does provide a very clean interface to communicate with “the outside world”. You can find the solution for this in the following hidden snippet:

```js
function createInterpreter (dataObj) {
  function initialize (intp, scope) {
    intp.setProperty(scope, 'get', intp.createNativeFunction(function (prop) {
      return intp.nativeToPseudo(dataObj[prop]);
    }), intp.READONLY_DESCRIPTOR);
    intp.setProperty(scope, 'set', intp.createNativeFunction(function (prop, value) {
      dataObj[prop] = intp.pseudoToNative(value);
    }), intp.READONLY_DESCRIPTOR);
  }

  return function (code) {
    const interpreter = new Interpreter(code, initialize);
    interpreter.run();
    return interpreter.value;
  };
}


let o = {
  hidden: null,
  regex: null,
  process: [
    "set('hidden', !get('visible'));",
    "set('regex', new RegExp(get('validate'), 'i'));"
  ],
  visible: true,
  validate: "^[a-z]+$"
};

const interprete = createInterpreter(o);
for (const process of o.process) {
  interprete(process);
}

console.log(o.hidden); // false
console.log(o.regex); // /^[a-z]+$/i
```

```html
<script src="https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/acorn_interpreter.js"></script>
```

---

However, after posting above solution, I just couldn’t stop thinking about this, so I dug deeper. As I learned, the methods `getProperty` and `setProperty` are not just used to set up the initial sandbox scope, but also as the code is being interpreted. So we can use this to create a proxy-like behavior for our object.

My solution here is based on code I found [in an issue comment](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter/issues/42#issuecomment-156802068) about doing this by modifying the `Interpreter` type. Unfortunately, the code is written in CoffeeScript and also based on some older versions, so we cannot use it exactly as it is. There’s also still the problem of the internals being minified, which we’ll get to in a moment.

The overall idea is to introduce a “connected object” into the scope which we will handle as a special case inside the `getProperty` and `setProperty` to map to our actual object.

But for that, we need to overwrite those two methods which is a problem because they are minified and received different internal names. Fortunately, the end of the source contains the following:

```
// Preserve top-level API functions from being pruned/renamed by JS compilers.
// …
Interpreter.prototype['getProperty'] = Interpreter.prototype.getProperty;
Interpreter.prototype['setProperty'] = Interpreter.prototype.setProperty;
```

So even if a minifier mangles the names on the right, it won’t touch the ones on the left. So that’s how the author made particular functions available for public use. But we want to *overwrite* them, so we cannot just overwrite the friendly names, we also need to replace the minified copies! But since we have a way to access the functions, we can also search for any other copy of them with a mangled name.

So that’s what I’m doing in my solution at the beginning in `patchInterpreter`: Define the new methods we’ll overwrite the existing ones with. Then, look for all the names (mangled or not) that refer to those functions, and replace them all with the new definition.

In the end, after patching the `Interpreter`, we just need to add a connected object into the scope. We cannot use the name `this` since that’s already used, but we can just choose something else, for example `o`:

```js
function patchInterpreter (Interpreter) {
  const originalGetProperty = Interpreter.prototype.getProperty;
  const originalSetProperty = Interpreter.prototype.setProperty;

  function newGetProperty(obj, name) {
    if (obj == null || !obj._connected) {
      return originalGetProperty.call(this, obj, name);
    }

    const value = obj._connected[name];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      // if the value is an object itself, create another connected object
      return this.createConnectedObject(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
  function newSetProperty(obj, name, value, opt_descriptor) {
    if (obj == null || !obj._connected) {
      return originalSetProperty.call(this, obj, name, value, opt_descriptor);
    }

    obj._connected[name] = this.pseudoToNative(value);
  }

  let getKeys = [];
  let setKeys = [];
  for (const key of Object.keys(Interpreter.prototype)) {
    if (Interpreter.prototype[key] === originalGetProperty) {
      getKeys.push(key);
    }
    if (Interpreter.prototype[key] === originalSetProperty) {
      setKeys.push(key);
    }
  }

  for (const key of getKeys) {
    Interpreter.prototype[key] = newGetProperty;
  }
  for (const key of setKeys) {
    Interpreter.prototype[key] = newSetProperty;
  }

  Interpreter.prototype.createConnectedObject = function (obj) {
    const connectedObject = this.createObject(this.OBJECT);
    connectedObject._connected = obj;
    return connectedObject;
  };
}
patchInterpreter(Interpreter);

// actual application code
function createInterpreter (dataObj) {
  function initialize (intp, scope) {
    // add a connected object for `dataObj`
    intp.setProperty(scope, 'o', intp.createConnectedObject(dataObj), intp.READONLY_DESCRIPTOR);
  }

  return function (code) {
    const interpreter = new Interpreter(code, initialize);
    interpreter.run();
    return interpreter.value;
  };
}


let o = {
  hidden: null,
  regex: null,
  process: [
    "o.hidden = !o.visible;",
    "o.regex = new RegExp(o.validate, 'i');"
  ],
  visible: true,
  validate: "^[a-z]+$"
};

const interprete = createInterpreter(o);
for (const process of o.process) {
  interprete(process);
}

console.log(o.hidden); // false
console.log(o.regex); // /^[a-z]+$/i
```

```html
<script src="https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/acorn_interpreter.js"></script>
```

And that’s it! Note that while that new implementation does already work with nested objects, it may not work with *every type*. So you should probably be careful what kind of objects you pass into the sandbox. It’s probably a good idea to create separate and explicitly safe objects with only basic or primitive types.

Comment: Not sure why my previous comment was deleted, but anyway amazing work. I wouldn't have come up with this ever. Bonus points pending!

Comment: I also have no idea why the comments were removed but I did see it when you posted it. As I’ve said before, it was a fun challenge – so you’re welcome! And thanks in advance for the bonus, really appreciate the gesture :)

Comment: A note for anyone trying this, if I add a parameter to `o`, say `array: [],`, then try the code `o.array.push(42);`, it comes up with `Uncaught TypeError: function push() { [native code] } is not a function`. It's pulling up native code which is incompatible with JS-Interpreter. I tried revising `newGetProperty` to return JS-Interpreter functions, but then it gets into another rabbit hole with incompatible objects. The `.length` property is available so `push` can be simulated, but `pop` and others might be harder. Just a heads up that the code in this context has to be really simple!

Comment: @YiminRong What you *could* do is check whether `value` in `newGetProperty` is an array and then return a pseudo array for it (basically `if (Array.isArray(value)) { return this.nativeToPseudo(value); }`). That way you still can’t do `o.array.push(42)` (well you can, but it won’t update the native array), but you could do `var x = o.array; x.push(42); o.array = x;` – So basically, you cannot *mutate* arrays but you can replace them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For my purposes, the only Array function I'm needing is `push` which can be replicated as `o.array[o.array.length] = value;`. With only a few revisions from your original code, I'm getting it to do amazing things!

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried `JS-Interpreter`. You can use `new Function()` and `Function.prototype.call()` to achieve requirement

```js
let o = {
    hidden: null,
    regex: null,
    process: [
        "this.hidden = !this.visible;",
        "this.regex = new RegExp(this.validate, 'i');"
    ],
    visible: true,
    validate: "^[a-z]+$"
};

for (let i = 0; i < o.process.length; i++)
    console.log(new Function(`return ${o.process[i]}`).call(o));
```

Comment: Thank you, your code does work so +1, but I'm still looking for solutions using JS-Interpreter because it provides means to prevent infinite loops and other “attacks”.

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be interpretWithinContext look like something like that ?

```
let interpretWithinContext = (function(o, p){
   //in dunno for what you use p because all is on object o
   o.hidden = (o.hidden === null) ? false : o.hidden;
   o.regex = (o.regex === null) ? '/^[a-z]+$/i' : o.regex;

   console.log(o);
   return o;
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGwyra?editors=1111

Comment: Think of `o` as a JSON object loaded from a file, and afterwards you want to run the code in `process` as defined in that file, so it can't be hard-coded.

Comment: @YiminRong i didn't understand the topic at all ;) this is confuse me interpretWithinContext ... , now is pretty clear for me.